# sbt-native-package Debian versus JDKPackager

Tags: scala, sbt-native-packager

I am trying to understand the differences between these two types of installers. Ideally I want to be able to *not* bundle Java but have (as it should be on Debian) a package dependency. This works for the [Debian plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/debian.html):

```
enablePlugins(DebianPlugin)

debianPackageDependencies in Debian += "java6-runtime"
```

Ideally I want to have a `.desktop` entry for my desktop manager (e.g. Gnome), handling icon, launch and jvm options, and file associations. This is automatically handled by the [JDKPackager plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/jdkpackager.html):

```
enablePlugins(JDKPackagerPlugin)

jdkAppIcon := ...

jdkPackagerJVMArgs := Seq("-Xmx1g")

jdkPackagerAssociations += FileAssociation(
  "foobar", "application/foobar", "Foobar file type", myIcon)
```

**How would I achieve an installation that combines these two features, package dependencies and desktop application integration?**

Comment: I think the jdkpackager is the way to go. It's configured with an ant build.xml . Check if it provides  way to exclude the jre. You can also create a feature request on our github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JDKPackager` inhabits a sort of parallel world to the other plugins, in that it attempts to translate the standard `sbt-native-packager` keys (and some additional ones) into the forms the Oracle Java 8 `javapackager` tool accepts, delegating all the "hard" work to the external tool. It does this via a set of Ant tasks delivered with the JDK, invoked through a `build.xml` file created in the `target/jdkpackager` directory.

On the `LinuxPlugin` side of things, they are built more from the ground up, likely with server-type applications in mind.

While Oracle continues to add new features to the `javapackger` system, the documentation for it is often spotty and incomplete (as of this writing), so there may be capabilities that are possible but not exposed via `sbt-native-packager` keys. If you find something in the Oracle Ant tasks that would help you achieve your end goals, don't hesitate to submit an issue or PR to the project. Exposing additional settings against Ant task parameters is generally an easy process.

You may also find that through the `javapackager` ["drop-in resources"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGICFDB) facility you can override certain parts of the generated `.deb` definition file. That said, I've only used it on MacOS and Windows (where it works, but is a bit fiddly), and don't know exactly what's exposed via the `.deb` and `.rpm` pipelines.